# How to overwrite a text file with streamwriter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm having issues when I try to overwrite a text file with other text. I get the error: "Stream was not writable."
This is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult FilterFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            var resultMessage = "";
            var text = "";
            var lineCount = 0;
            try
            {
                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var stream = file.InputStream;

                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {

                        var line = "";
                        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            lineCount++;
                            if (line.Split(' ').Count() > 1)
                            {
                                var number = line.Split(' ')[0];
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(number))
                                    line = line.Replace(number, "");
                                text = text + line + Environment.NewLine;
                            }

                        }

                        var sw = new StreamWriter(stream);

                        foreach (var l in text)
                        {
                            sw.Write(l);
                        }
                    }
                }

                resultMessage = "The task was completed successfully!!";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                resultMessage = ex.Message;
            }
            return Json(resultMessage);
        }
```

I would really appreciate if someone can help me since I'm new to all of this. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand it. Why are you trying to write into the `InputStream`? It's not surprising you cannot do that...

Comment: I agree with the computer, that stream belongs to a HttpPostedFile, so a blob of binary that the user uploaded. It'll be in-memory and likely readonly. Open a stream to a whole new file instead, or skip the stream and handle the byte array directly.

Comment: Thanks for answering but now I get this error:"Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\Test.txt' is denied."

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, [`HttpPostedFileBase.InputStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.inputstream(v=vs.110).aspx) is:

> An object for reading a file.

That stream is opened only for reading.

To be able to write into a stream, you need a stream which is opened for writing. For example:

```
var writableStream = new FileStream(
    @"filename.txt",
    FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
    FileAccess.ReadWrite);

var sw = new StreamWriter(writableStream);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but now I get this error:"Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\Test.txt' is denied." This is not the correct path. Please help. thanks.

Comment: Also I would like to overwrite the same file that it was reading from.

Comment: @BYG The process does not have access to your path.  Write the file to a subdirectory of your project, or give the account running your site access to the directory you want to write to.

Comment: Yeah, as @Fran wrote. And I don't think you can write into the same file you're reading from. The reason is that it's already opened exclusively for reading. You would have to open it for both reading and writing but you cannot open already opened file, you would have to close it first.